# Multidimensional Array to path

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi I have a multidimensional array of 1ns and 0es. the 0es are ordered into a mass that I wish to extrude into a shape using 3js. Unfortunately to extrude 3js requires a path when defining a shape object not a multidimensional array. I am using JQuery and 3js.

E.G.
    [0,0,0,1,0,
     0,0,1,1,0
     0,1,1,0,0]

to become
    moveTo(X,Y)
    lineTo(X,Y)
    so on and so forth

I am using this to auto generate a cave system.
this is my current attempt

```
function toPath(array){
for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
 for (var j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
  if (array[i][j]===0 && countAliveNeighbours(array, i, j)>0){
   points[i+":"+j]=[false,false,false,false];//lurd

   if ((i+1)>0 && (i+1)<array.length){//right
    if (array[i+1][j]===1){
     points[i+":"+j][2]=true;
    }
   }
   if ((i-1)>0 && (i-1)<array.length){//left
    if (array[i-1][j]===1){
     points[i+":"+j][0]=true;
    }
   }
   if ((j+1)>0 && (j+1)<array[i].length){//down
    if (array[i][j+1]===1){
     points[i+":"+j][3]=true;
    }
   }
   if ((j-1)>0 && (j-1)<array[i].length){//up
    if (array[i][j-1]===1){
     points[i+":"+j][1]=true;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
return points;
```

}

```
var template=toPath(array);
var caveBase = new THREE.Shape();

for (var property in template){
 var points=property.split(":");
 var X=points[0]*3;
 var Y=points[1]*3;

 caveBase.moveTo(X,Y);

var directions=template[property];

if (directions[0]){caveBase.moveTo(X-1,Y+1);caveBase.lineTo(X-1,Y-1);}
if (directions[1]){caveBase.moveTo(X-1,Y-1);caveBase.lineTo(X+1,Y-1);}
if (directions[2]){caveBase.moveTo(X+1,Y+1);caveBase.lineTo(X+1,Y-1);}
if (directions[3]){caveBase.moveTo(X-1,Y+1);caveBase.lineTo(X+1,Y+1);}
```

}

Comment: You need to add your expected result with details. i. e. instead of `X` and `Y` you should provide the exact values you are expecting based on the input array. You also need to include the code you tried so far.

Comment: Where's your attempt?  What have you tried so far?